# I can't access the internet from my ec2 instance after switching the static IP addressing

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I followed this article here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-private-ip-address/ in order to add multiple IPs to my instance.

Now, I can access all my sites from outside of the EC2 instance, but if I fire up a web browser from within my instance, I can't access the internet. This did not happen until I made the above noted change.

Everything else seems to be functioning correctly. Setup the instance with the default VPC settings.

Any help is greatly appreciated. New to AWS.

Win 2016 Server

Comment: I'd do an "ipconfig" to see what's up there, and poke around in network settings, and post any info you have. What troubleshooting have you done? Have you read [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html), and forum questions like [this one](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102694)?

Comment: First link you posted is the article I followed. Second link having some difficulty with. Trying to figure out the ACLs section to see if it's relevant in my case. Main issue is, I followed the article to the T and made no other changes. All of this was working fine before. Thank you, still looking/reading on it.

Comment: I'll post more updates soon, with ipconfig info.